# Laravel Eloquent - Using pivot table's id as a foreign key in another table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I need to use pivot table's id as a foreign key in another table.

for example i have following tables:

```
users: id, username, ...

places: id, placename, lat, lng, ...

place_user: id, user_id, place_id

routes: place_user_id, lat, lng, inserted_at.
```

so when user says I am going to that place, I have a new entry in place_user table and start to log the route he takes to get there. So for each place_user entry i have many entries in routes table.

what is the correct way of doing this kind of relationship using eloquent? Should I create a model for the pivot table?

I have tried to solve my problem by the following solution but no luck: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2093#issuecomment-39154456 and posted a comment there https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2093#issuecomment-58187802

any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want a relationship between `users` and `places`, using the `place_user` table. What is the `routes` table for?

Comment: I have many to many relationship between users and places, and one to many relationship between routes and place_user relationship table.

Comment: You need to use additional model for your pivot table, one extending `Model` (`Eloquent`) not `Pivot`. `Pivot` has constructor that will make it impossible to work with. If you need to use the `pivot` property (in the context of a relation) then you need also custom pivot model (extending `Pivot`) only for this case.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After lots of searching and trying different solutions I came up with the following solution:

**User Model:**

```
class User extends \Eloquent {
    public function places() {
        return $this->hasMany('PlaceUser')->with('Place');
    }
}
```

**Place Model:**

```
class Place extends \Eloquent {
    public function users() {
        return $this->hasMany('PlaceUser')->with('User');
    }
}
```

**PlaceUser Model:**

```
class PlaceUser extends \Eloquent {

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    public function place() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Place');
    }

    public function footprints() {
        return $this->hasMany('Footprint');
    }
}
```

I have Changed name route to footprint to avoid problems with route class included in laravel.

**Footprint Model:**

```
class Footprint extends \Eloquent {
    public function place_user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('PlaceUser');
    }
}
```

In the end I get structure where I can make different queries like:

```
// gets all places with corresponding pivot table entries and users table entries    
Place::with('users')->get(); 
// get user with id=1 including corresponding pivot table entries and places table entries
User::with('places')->find(1); 
// get footprint of the user
$user->places->get(0)->footprints
```

hope this helps

Comment: I guess I will come up with your solution too with my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59085303/is-it-possible-to-get-the-relation-of-a-pivot-table-to-another-table-in-laravel