# Is it possible to bind an additional relationship to the intermediate pivot value?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Lets say I use a relationship like this one below:

```
public function features()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(ProductFeature::class, 'product_feature', 'product_id', 'feature_id')
        ->withPivot('variant_id');
}
```

Here I can return the **variant_id** of the particular feature. I am wondering if it possible to use a belongsTo (or other) relationship on the **variant_id** so that I could access the variant details at the same time?

**PS:** I think using an **array where all the variants are stored** with the id key could do the job but would great if I could use a pivot relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a model which represents the pivot table, retrieve all the features via a hasMany relationship with the pivot table, and then retrieve the product and the variant via a belongsTo relationship.

More info: [Laravel Eloquent - Using pivot table's id as a foreign key in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26238639/laravel-eloquent-using-pivot-tables-id-as-a-foreign-key-in-another-table)