# Is it possible to get the relation of a pivot table to another table in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have a training app that currently has this schema:

```
trainings
id
name

speakers
id
first_name
last_name

training_speaker
id
training_id
speaker_id

training_speaker_dates
id
training_speaker_id
date
time
```

A training can have multiple speakers, and a speaker can have multiple trainings. Currently, I'm accessing the training speakers by its pivot model.

```
class Training {
  public function speakers() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Speaker')->using('App\TrainingSpeaker');
  }
}
```

Let's say we have a 3-day training, a speaker can attend the first day and maybe just the morning, that's why the `training_speaker_dates` has date and time(morning of afternoon).

Is it possible to also include the `training_speaker_dates` in the speakers method under Training class?

Or, should I just remove the `training_speaker_dates` and add the fields to `training_speakers` table and allow duplicate values (training_id & speaker_id) with unique id? So then it'll look like this

```
training_speaker
id
training_id
speaker_id
date
time
```

Comment: Don't know if it is possible without using third party packages or without implementing some sort of a has many through yourself. But, any reason why you have not used `date` and `time` as pivot attributes on the `training_speaker` table?

Comment: @user3532758 I am using the attach method when storing in training_speaker so I can only save one I guess with unique training_id and speaker_id

Comment: Ah! I see. Because there was `id` I thought you may have planned to have repeating pairs there. I have previously used `syncWithoutDetaching` in a similar situation. Sorry I couldn't help and hope someone with more experience comes along. Good luck anyways.

Comment: No worries @user3532758 mate! Thank you for sharing your idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class Training {
  public function trainingspeakerdates() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Trainingspeakerdates','training_speaker_id','id')->using('App\TrainingSpeaker');
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I need to access the speakers first and attach the dates for each speaker.